# How can I reply this type of alignment? And, How could I add a "constant" text to all even rows?

Tags: math-mode, alignment, logic

[image]

I would like to define an environment to have different alignments in even and odd rows, and add the equiv symbol in all even rows.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Should the `\equiv` symbol stick out into the right-hand margin? How will line breaks be created? What about rows? Please advise.

Comment: I tried using a tabluar environment reducing space between columns, but the problem is to write \equiv in the first column of all even rows. If there is a way of use rows (as I understood from what you say) I have no idea how

Comment: You could just add a \quad at the start of every other line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to mark up the various parts. I used `\wff` (well-formed formula) for the main lines and `\why` for the justification. Choose your own preferred names.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\wff}[1]{& (#1) \\}
\newcommand{\why}[1]{\equiv{}&\quad\langle\;\text{#1}\;\rangle \\}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\wff{\phi \land \psi}
\why{Ax11}
\wff{\phi \equiv (\psi \equiv (\phi \lor \psi))}
\why{conmutatividad de $\lor$}
\wff{\phi \equiv \psi \equiv (\psi \lor \phi))}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different approach by “line number”: odd-numbered lines are treated like `\wff` in the previous code, even-numbered ones like `\why`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{derivation}{b}
 {
  \davidgomez_derivation:n { #1 }
 }
 {\ignorespacesafterend}

\seq_new:N \l__davidgomez_derivation_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__davidgomez_derivation_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \davidgomez_derivation:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__davidgomez_derivation_in_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__davidgomez_derivation_out_seq
  \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn \l__davidgomez_derivation_in_seq
   {
    \int_if_odd:nTF { ##1 }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__davidgomez_derivation_out_seq { & (##2) }
     }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__davidgomez_derivation_out_seq { \equiv & \quad\langle\;\text{##2}\;\rangle }
     }
   }
  \begin{align*}
  \seq_use:Nn \l__davidgomez_derivation_out_seq { \\ }
  \end{align*}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{derivation}
  \phi \land \psi \\
Ax11 \\
  \phi \equiv (\psi \equiv (\phi \lor \psi)) \\
conmutatividad de $\lor$ \\
  \phi \equiv \psi \equiv (\psi \lor \phi))
\end{derivation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use an environment which enables left alignment and use `\llap{$\equiv$}\quad` at even rows. For example, in Plain TeX:

```
\def\lequiv{\llap{$\equiv$}\quad}
$$
  \eqalign{
    &         (\phi\wedge\psi) \cr
    & \lequiv \langle\ {\it Ax}11\ \rangle \cr
    &         (\phi \equiv (\psi \equiv (\phi \vee \psi))) \cr
    & \lequiv \langle\ \hbox{conmutativiad de $\vee$}\ \rangle \cr
    &         (\phi \equiv (\psi \equiv (\psi \vee \phi)) \cr
  }
$$
\bye
```